# Check if graph is regular given adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have the following problem:

> Write a function
> whose input is an adjacency matrix A of a graph G. The function returns true
> if G is a regular graph and false otherwise.

I understand that a graph is regular if the degrees of all the vertices are the same.

Therefore, I have written the following code which calculates the amount of degrees for each column:

```python
def sumColumns(A):
  columns = []
  for i in range(0, len(A[0])):
    total = 0
    for j in range(0, len(A)):
      total += A[j][i]
    if total > 0:
      columns.append(total)
  return columns

def isRegularGraph(A):

  # Get list of degrees
  cd = sumColumns(A)

  if not len(cd) > 0 or  cd[0] != cd[len(cd) - 1]:
    return False
  
  # Do comparisons from i to i - 1
  for i in range(0, len(cd) - 1):
    if cd[i] != cd[i + 1]:
      return False
  return True
```

My question is, do I also need to check row wise if the number of degrees are the same column wise?

Is there a better algorithm to do this?

Comment: Better in what way? Your solution is very simple and easy to understand, but you can also test for regularity via eigenvalues or eigenvectors. For these there are well-known standard results.

Comment: If your graph is undirected, the adjacency matrix is symmetric, so you've already checked all rows when you are done checking columns.

Comment: @Juho, thanks I wasn't aware of such case using eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre, that's correct and makes perfect sense to me, thank you!

Comment: The equivalent condition in terms of eigenvectors is just that the vector of ones $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is an eigenvector. It doesn't really help you, since checking that this vector is an eigenvector is the same work as adding along the rows and checking if you always get the same value.

Comment: If you only need to check regularity and nothing else, you can reduce the memory use by not storing the sums of all rows. You only need the sum of the first one and the sum of the current column that you are computing.

Comment: You implementation also has some problems. You are discarding sums that are zero. That means that if you have a graph that is the union of a regular graph of positive degree and some isolated vertices, then you still say that it is regular.

Comment: @plop, I understand what you mean, thanks a lot.